# Javascript: how to read a random line from a txt file locally when button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, random, import

Im building a website for a school project.  When the button is pressed it will generate a random word from a txt file of words.  Each word is on its own line.  What I want the script file to is read each word (line) from the text file, put the words into an array.  An read a random word when the button is pressed.  The main issue is that I do not know the code or methods used to read a file in javascript. I looked at similar posts on here about how to read line from a text file, but they all involved going over the server to read it.  I'm working locally and am not using a server.  Any information about how to read a text file from javascript thats all client-side?

Comment: look into FileReader() and <input type=file>'s files[] collection

Comment: @dandavis could you elaborate a little more?  Not sure what you mean by files collection

Comment: Reading a file with-out user interaction from the local hard disk is not possible (security concerns). You can only read a file with FileAPI if a user selects one from a file picker dialog. I would store your data in JSON files these are easier readable from javascript.

Comment: If i still wanted to work with a local text file what would an alternative be?  I know how to make a python file where it can read the line from a file, just not sure how to incorporate with html.  - @AWolf

Comment: Have a look at [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) that's a framework to write python code that creates a web page. Then you can read your file with python.

Comment: Firefox allows you to establish AJAX connections in `file` scheme (but won't allow to access files in parent folders). But Chrome doesn't.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to read a file provided by the site visitor, or a file that *you* made in the same directory as your web project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it by using `Math.Random()` and because you have each word in each line you can just take the random number genarated and read the word

Comment: The problem is reading a local file, not choosing the line to read.